# Expression inference during inheritance

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, expression-trees, type-inference

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Descendant d = new Descendant();
        d.TestMethod();
    }
}

public class Base
{
    protected void FigureItOut<TClass, TMember>(Expression<Func<TClass, TMember>> expr)
    {

    }
}

public class Descendant : Base
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        FigureItOut(c => c.Name);
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I get this compiler error message:

```
The type arguments for method
'Base.FigureItOut<TClass,TMember> 
(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TClass,TMember>>)'
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

If I change the call to FigureItOut to this:

```
FigureItOut((Descendant c) => c.Name);
```

Then it works. Is there a way to get the first example to compile by changing the base class instead?

I know that if I make the entire Base class generic, like this:

```
public class Base<TDescendant>
{
    protected void FigureItOut<TMember>(Expression<Func<TDescendant, TMember>> expr)
    {

    }
}

public class Descendant : Base<Descendant>
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        FigureItOut(c => c.Name);
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then it works, but I'd rather not do that, any other hacks that can be employed, perhaps on the method level (ie. change FigureItOut somehow).

Comment: I've added an alternative that avoids the `internal` requirement (and the extension method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about an extension method that calls the actual (`protected internal`) implementation? The only downside is you have to add `this.`.

This works because the `source` parameter (via `this`) infers a type for `TClass`.

```
public class Base
{
    protected internal void FigureItOut<TClass, TMember>(Expression<Func<TClass, TMember>> expr)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Got to actual method");
    }
}

public static class BaseExt
{
    public static void FigureItOut<TClass, TMember>(this TClass source, Expression<Func<TClass, TMember>> expr)
        where TClass : Base
    { // call the actual method
        Debug.WriteLine("Got to extension method");
        source.FigureItOut(expr);
    }
}
public class Descendant : Base
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        this.FigureItOut(c => c.Name);
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

As an alternative (if the `internal` is a pain), consider making it static, with an instance argument that is used primarily for type inference:

```
protected static void FigureItOut<TClass, TMember>(TClass source, Expression<Func<TClass, TMember>> expr)
{

}

public void TestMethod()
{
    FigureItOut(this, c => c.Name);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this solves another problem, related to some diamond-shaped inheritance problem, but it also exposes the FigureItOut method to outsiders, we'll have to consider if that is a tradeoff we can live with.

Comment: @lassevk - well, internal outsiders... note that you could make BaseExt internal too...

Comment: Problem is, and know I didn't state this in the question, but the Base class is in a class library, and the descendant is in another, or in an application project, so there's still some issues here

Comment: @lassevk - in that case, consider just a protected static method on Base that accepts an instance as the first argument, and use FigureItOut(this, c=>c.Name) - almost as good.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it takes a parameter, it cant be inferred.
Unless it assigns a return value, it cant be inferred.

Comment: Don't forget that arg0 (aka "this") is *also* a parameter that can drive type inference, especially via extension methods.